# pre-commit hooks terminate if previous stage fails

Tags: pre-commit-hook, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

I'm using the pre-commit hooks configuration https://pre-commit.com/ to enable pre-commit hooks

```
repos:
  - repo: local
    hooks:
      - id: pytest-check
        name: pytest-check
        entry: pytest
        language: system
        pass_filenames: false
        always_run: false
      - id: flake8
        name: flake8
        entry: flake8
        language: python
        types: [python]
        args: ['src/']
```

If `pytest-check` fails it will also execute the `flake8` hook.
Is it possible to terminate the execution if a previous hook failed, in this case flake8 would not run if the pytest-check failed.
I read through the docs but couldn't find any information on this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you're looking for `fail_fast: true`

it can be specified both [at the top level](https://pre-commit.com/#top_level-fail_fast) and [at the hook level](https://pre-commit.com/#hooks-fail_fast)

---

an aside you have a few unrelated problems with your configuration:

- ~generally you don't want to run tests as part of `pre-commit`, they'll be slow which will frustrate your users and often lead to them turning the whole thing off
- `always_run: false` is the default, no need to specify it
- flake8 as you've configured it is both double-linting and fork bombing (you're passing `src/` and pre-commit is additionally passing filenames, and you've misconfigured the multiprocessing mode) -- I'd recommend using the `pycqa/flake8` repository directly which configures this correctly
- for `repo: local` hooks there's no reason to use `args` -- just specify it directly in `entry`

---

disclaimer: I wrote pre-commit